How to combine material chips and menu?
I need to combine material chip and menu in angular application.
I am trying to understand it on conceptual level.
There is a chip that triggers menu. On the other hand, menu items should be selectable options (with multiselect).
Is menu just an UI wrapper around checkboxes which I access directly like in any other form?
How should I organize that?

if menu has checkboxes, its a multiselect dropdown not a select, please update the exact requirement and the code you tried, so that there is some reference on what you want

Try the code below, which combines Material chips and a menu.
Html file:
<form>
  <mat-form-field class="example-chip-list">
    <mat-label>Favorite Fruits</mat-label>
    <mat-chip-grid #chipGrid aria-label="Fruit selection">
      @for (fruit of fruits(); track $index) {
        <mat-chip-row (removed)="remove(fruit)">
          {{fruit}}
          <button matChipRemove [attr.aria-label]="'remove ' + fruit">
            <mat-icon>cancel</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </mat-chip-row>
      }
    </mat-chip-grid>
    <input
      name="currentFruit"
      placeholder="New Fruit..."
      #fruitInput
      [(ngModel)]="currentFruit"
      [matChipInputFor]="chipGrid"
      [matAutocomplete]="auto"
      [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
      (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)"
    />
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event)">
      @for (fruit of filteredFruits(); track fruit) {
        <mat-option [value]="fruit">{{fruit}}</mat-option>
      }
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>

Ts file:
import {LiveAnnouncer} from '@angular/cdk/a11y';
import {COMMA, ENTER} from '@angular/cdk/keycodes';
import {ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, computed, inject, model, signal} from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {MatAutocompleteModule, MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent} from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import {MatChipInputEvent, MatChipsModule} from '@angular/material/chips';
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';

@Component({
  selector: 'chips-autocomplete-example',
  templateUrl: 'chips-autocomplete-example.html',
  styleUrl: 'chips-autocomplete-example.css',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MatFormFieldModule, MatChipsModule, MatIconModule, MatAutocompleteModule, FormsModule],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class ChipsAutocompleteExample {
  readonly separatorKeysCodes: number[] = [ENTER, COMMA];
  readonly currentFruit = model('');
  readonly fruits = signal(['Lemon']);
  readonly allFruits: string[] = ['Apple', 'Lemon', 'Lime', 'Orange', 'Strawberry'];
  readonly filteredFruits = computed(() => {
    const currentFruit = this.currentFruit().toLowerCase();
    return currentFruit
      ? this.allFruits.filter(fruit => fruit.toLowerCase().includes(currentFruit))
      : this.allFruits.slice();
  });

  readonly announcer = inject(LiveAnnouncer);

  add(event: MatChipInputEvent): void {
    const value = (event.value || '').trim();

    // Add our fruit
    if (value) {
      this.fruits.update(fruits => [...fruits, value]);
    }

    // Clear the input value
    this.currentFruit.set('');
  }

  remove(fruit: string): void {
    this.fruits.update(fruits => {
      const index = fruits.indexOf(fruit);
      if (index < 0) {
        return fruits;
      }

      fruits.splice(index, 1);
      this.announcer.announce(`Removed ${fruit}`);
      return [...fruits];
    });
  }

  selected(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent): void {
    this.fruits.update(fruits => [...fruits, event.option.viewValue]);
    this.currentFruit.set('');
    event.option.deselect();
  }
}

